# Irregular TIMEOUTs in Docker Operations between GCP GKE and AWS ECR

Tags: timeout, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-ecr

In my company, we have a GitLab CI/CD pipeline running on the GitLab Runner on Kubernetes (GKE). In that process, we push Docker images to a private repository in AWS ECR. The processes access the Internet through Cloud NAT.

This worked for several months with no issues until two weeks ago, when we started getting timeout errors such as below:

`Error response from daemon: Get https://<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

This is not consistent and, sometimes, the process finishes successfully. Also, the messages vary because this sometimes happen during `docker login`, other times during `docker push`. Finally, retries during push like below didn't use to happen in the past, but now they happen a lot.

`Retrying in 5 seconds ... Retrying in 1 second`

**Have you guys ever faced something similar to this situation?**

I've already tried some solutions I found online such as: reducing `--max-concurrent-uploads` or setting `--dns 8.8.8.8` on the Docker Daemon. Also, I've tried increasing the Cloud NAT's `Minimum ports per VM instance` option and changing the `TCP TIME_WAIT Timeout`. No success with any of these.

We have other pipelines in the company, but only this one access ECR. No issues accessing any other endpoint.

Comment: I could not find a solution for this issue, so I decided to create a Runner instance on AWS for that pipeline instead, and it's working fine as expected. I've also tested pushing the images to the Artifact Registry instead of ECR and that was fine as well, but I didn't go further with this and decided to just use the "Runner on AWS" solution.